# ios swift storyboard and xibs

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, xib

so I have a main storyboard that is huge due to inheriting the project

what I need to do is add an outlet to the storyboard and then have it open the first screen I need and then a view controller manages when the show the second screen.

i.e.

```
Main.storyboard, which has ViewController.swift working as designed
FirstScreen.xib, also FirstScreen.swift that is a UIViewController
SecondScreen.xib, also SecondScreen.swift that is a UIViewController
...
EighthScreen.xib, also EighthScreen.swift that is a UIViewController
```

where you might not go from 1..2..3..4..5..6..7..8 in this wizard
you might choose 1..2..8 due to screen 2 options saying "ok next step is 8"

does anyone have something I can read or a tutorial I can follow?

we don't need a full blown story board we need to be able to have a xib with a next/previous button to go back and forth.

Answer (score 0):

Did you make it so that the storyboard entry is to the nib file not really sure what you are asking here.